# Automating web requests using curl?

Tags: curl, web

I have some "corporative" systems I have to use at work. Some of them are terrible, with frames, pop-ups and such.

I was thinking about automating some stuff using curl or something like that. I need login, click on hyperlinks, set some data, and them do some post.

Is it possible to use curl? Or am I'm going to be better using something like Selenium?

Comment: I would use Python's [zope.testbrowser](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zope.testbrowser) for that.

Comment: Do you need to be able to use Javascript?

Comment: Related: [Are there any good tools besides SeleniumRC that can fetch webpages including content post-painted by JavaScript?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/are-there-any-good-tools-besides-seleniumrc-that-can-fetch-webpages-including-con)

Comment: Using a session is just sending the session id with each request. Either in a cookie or in GET parameter. `wget` and `curl` can use Netscape cookie file, so if your browser also use such one, may be enough to just specify it to the downloader. So, what kind of browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome the most. sometimes Opera and Firefox

Comment: No luck for a simple solution with those. Firefox and Chrome uses SQLite, Opera has a binary data file format. Looks like you will have to search for the session id and pass it manually to the downloader.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it's fully possible with curl.  Most importantly will be to save and reload cookies between uses of curl with `--cookie-jar`.  You can also post form data as needed.  I usually use a Firefox add-on called Live HTTP Headers to capture what happens when I navigate a website.  It will record any headers, but also any form posts which is very helpful when trying to figure out what to do with curl.  I've written bash scripts automating various curl invocations and use pipes and temporary files (courtesy of `mktemp`) to do some limited processing on the webpage, but if have to do a lot of webpage processing I usually switch to Perl with LibWWW.

Comment: In addition to Firefox Live HTTP Headers, both Safari and Chrome can display the headers broken down by object in the Web Inspector.

Answer (score 17):

For simple cases of **downloading** the contents of a page, use **[curl](http://curl.haxx.se)** or **[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/wget.html)**. Both are command line tools designed to download files over HTTP and have many options. In your case, you'll likely need to make these tools look more like a browser; [lutzky's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26385/use-command-line-to-download-file-which-is-accessible-only-in-a-given-session/26439#26439) and [penguin359's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/does-anybody-here-have-experience-in-automating-some-tasks-in-web-applications-u/11336#11336) mention some curl and wget options that are useful in that respect.

Sometimes, when you need to **log in**, it's a lot easier to first log in manually in a web browser, then **export the web browser's cookies** (extensions like [allcookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/allcookies/) or [Export Cookies](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/export-cookies/) for Firefox can help).

If you need to **parse the contents** of some pages or **post forms**, you may need fancier tools than curl and wget. Some good tools there are Perl with **[`LWP` (libwww)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/)** and **[`HTML::TreeBuilder` (HTML-Tree)](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree/)** or Python with standard libraries (especially **[`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) and [`htmllib`](http://docs.python.org/library/htmllib.html)**).

For more **complex interactions** with a website, the reference is Perl's **[WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?WWW::Mechanize)**. This Perl library defines high-level functions to interact with a website like a web browser does, including POSTing, forms, cookies, but not Javascript. If Perl isn't your cup of tea, this library has imitations with similar capabilities in other languages, such as **[Python mechanize](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize)** and **[Ruby Mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/)**.

Finally, when you need **Javascript**, the usual approach is to use a web browser which is driven by a browser automation framework. **[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)** and [Watir](http://watir.com/) are popular choices; see also [Are there any good tools besides SeleniumRC that can fetch webpages including content post-painted by JavaScript?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/are-there-any-good-tools-besides-seleniumrc-that-can-fetch-webpages-including-co)

Answer (score 6):

My favorite is `wget`, so I'll give an example with that. What you want to do is replicate your browser session as closely as possible, so use the relevant commandline arguments. The ones which are necessary depend on how thoroughly the site checks your browser. `--referer` (sic) is usually sufficient, but you might also need `--user-agent` and `--load-cookies`.

This technique is basically browser spoofing - you're trying to get `wget` to present itself to the site as the browser. The biggest problem you'll be facing is CAPTCHA, which is not present in the example site you've given. Also, make sure you abide by the site's timing policies (45 seconds in this case), or you'll probably get blocked.

It's probably *not* possible to download the same file across different sessions - the site grants downloading privileges on the specific file to a specific session.

Comment: Good answer with comprehensive considerations. Thanks