# Are there any good tools besides SeleniumRC that can fetch webpages including content post-painted by JavaScript?

Tags: wget, http, html, curl, selenium

One major shortcoming of `curl` is that more and more wepages are having their main piece of content painted by a JavaScript AJAX response that occurs after the initial HTTP response. `curl` never picks up on this post-painted content.

So to fetch these types of webpages from the command line, I've been reduced to writing scripts in Ruby that drive the SeleniumRC to fire up a Firefox instance and then return the source HTML after these AJAX calls have completed.

It would be much better to have a leaner command line solution for this type of problem.  Does anyone know of any?

Comment: No one's suggested anything else on [Does anybody here have experience in automating some tasks in web applications using curl?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/does-anybody-here-have-experience-in-automating-some-tasks-in-web-applications-us), but that question wasn't specifically asking about scraping Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently started using the WebDriver from Selenium 2 in Java.  There is a driver called HtmlUnitDriver that fully supports JavaScript but does not fire up an actual browser.

It is not a light solution but it does get the job done.

I've designed the code to run from the command line and save the web data to files.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered Watir?

http://watir.com/

When you've added the package, you can run it as a standalone file or from `irb`, line-by-line after `include 'watir-webdriver'`. I've found it to be more responsive than `selenium-webdriver`, but without the test recording GUI to help work out complex test conditions.