# Javascript to HTML converter?

Tags: scripting, download, javascript

Take for example this snippet of code on a web page.

```
<html><body>
<script language="javascript">
document.write("The cat");
document.write(" sat on the mat");
</script>
</body></html>
```

If I were to retrieve this web page via CURL or WGET I would get that text because the Javascript has not been processed.

But I would like to retrieve this page, so I get the results of the Javascript output. So I would get just..

```
The cat sat on the mat
```

Is there some Linux Javascript sandbox/emulator/pre processor or something of that ilk that would allow me to process that text into html. I understand Javascript is complex and don't expect 100% conversion. But even to get some basic conversion would be helpful.

I know its possible as I'm sure Google does that when they index web pages to get the best results for the web pages they index.

Answer (score 7):

There's no such thing as a “Javascript to HTML converter”. Javascript is a programming language, not a markup language. Browsers don't convert Javascript to HTML, they execute the Javascript code, and the effect of the Javascript code is to modify the HTML. What you're after is a Javascript interpreter that can process the HTML document.

One way to do this is to use a browser engine behind the scenes. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) and [Watir](http://watir.com/) (both web application testing engines) are popular choices to call a web browser and drive it with a script — see [Are there any good tools besides SeleniumRC that can fetch webpages including content post-painted by JavaScript?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12186/are-there-any-good-tools-besides-seleniumrc-that-can-fetch-webpages-including-co).

There are also recent interfaces to Javascript and the DOM in several programming languages such as [Jswebkit](https://code.google.com/p/gwrite/) in [Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebBrowserProgramming) ([example](http://snipplr.com/view/66996/)).

Another possibility is to run [node.js](http://nodejs.org/), which is a standalone JavaScript interpreter ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392532/load-a-web-page-execute-its-javascript-and-dump-resulting-html-to-a-file)).

Comment: Thanks, it was difficult to state the question in a form where someone wouldn't try to explain to me the nature of javascript. But my example showed what I meant. The node.js looks promising, will try that out to see how well it does the job of "converting javascript to html" :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [elinks with Javascript](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manual.html#ecmascript) support. Once it is build just type:

> elinks --dump 1 http://www.example.com/my-js-page.html

and that should do it. Their documentation says that the Javascript support isn't great but this is another way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, there technically is a way to convert JavaScript to HTML.

I use inspect element in Chrome and FireFox a lot, which is the first place I learned HTML. If you paste a JavaScript in inspect element, it won't recognize it's function. I found a way around it. I taught myself everything I know which is what made it easier to figure this out. Here is an example:

Javascript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

JavaScript to HTML:

```
getElementById('demo').innerHTML='Hello World';
```

HTML reads HTML codes differently than JavaScripts so I have to simplify the JavaScript to get the HTML code. Technically it is a JavaScript since it carries out the JavaScript function but it is still HTML because it is in HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (or [casperJS](http://casperjs.org/), which sits on top of phantomJS) for doing such tasks. `console.log()` is used to log to `stdout`. You could even do [screen captures](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html).