# Use command line to download file which is accessible only in a given session

Tags: command-line, http, session, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anybody here have experience in automating some tasks in web applications using curl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/does-anybody-here-have-experience-in-automating-some-tasks-in-web-applications-u)

Sorry for the lengthy title.

I am trying use command line to download a file,which can only be accessed in a given session.

Like [this one](http://uploading.com/files/ecb2ma59/Ubuntu.Studio.11.04.amd64.part3.rar/):

You do not know the exact path of the file, so I could not download it **directly**.

I have three questions:

1. How to use Linux command line to download it?
2. What is this special download technique called? How does it work?
3. Is this possible to download the same file across sessions?