# What command line tools are available for testing Web Service?

Tags: command-line, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does anybody here have experience in automating some tasks in web applications using curl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/does-anybody-here-have-experience-in-automating-some-tasks-in-web-applications-u)

There are a number of GUI based tools to test Web Service (e.g. soapUI)

Is there any our command line driven tool that can be used to test a Webservice. Not just the connectivity, but also capture and compare the result returned by a web service

Comment: I've written a few by hand, always without the input-validation common to the "real" clients so that I could send bad inputs to the web service itself.

Answer (score 1):

either `wget`, or `perl` with one of the `soap modules`

Answer (score 1):

There is also `curl` - my personal favorite (imho more flexible than `wget`).

If you intend to monitor your web-servers don`t forget to set a special agent-string, so you can differentiate who accessed your server (if you do statistics).