# How to use cURL commandline to download a file, for which the link is hidden(activates on-click only)

Tags: curl

I was referring to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33456/how-to-use-wget-or-other-tool-to-download-a-file-for-which-the-link-is-hiddena). However, I am wondering how to do the same with `curl`.

So far, I have tried the following:

```
curl -O output.rar --referer http://subs.sab.bz/ 'http://subs.sab.bz/index.php?s=ece2929c25861a7244025e1628e7ee5a&act=download&attach_id=75766'
```

I also tried with `-e` switch, but it does not work for me.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) Firefox addon

Comment: How does cliget work? I could not find enough detail about it. I have downloaded its add on, but dont now how to use it

Comment: Just press a link and in a usual `Save this file` window or something similar you will see a curl command generated by cliget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that if I just:

```
url='http://subs.sab.bz/index.php?s=ece2929c25861a7244025e1628e7ee5a&act=download&attach_id=75766'
curl -e "$url" "$url" >out.rar
```

Then I could:

```
unrar e out.rar
```

And the results were:

```
Extracting from out.rar

Extracting  Dominion.S01E01.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.srt              OK
Extracting  Dominion.S01E01.HDTV.x264-LOL.srt                         OK
Extracting  Dominion.S01E01.HDTV.XviD-AFG.srt                         OK
Extracting  - README - subs.sab.bz - Brought to you by  xen.headoff.com -.html
  OK
All OK
```

So it seems to be perfectly willing to accept the download link itself as the referrer.

Comment: Its a great help, it works for me now. I have 1 more query, I have an HTML page on which several links are there, I want to click one link and that will download relevant file for me.  How do I simulate this using curl, any Idea? All links have different name attribute

Comment: @SAR - thats not a lot to go on, unfortunately. I would recommend you ask another question.