# Need to write an automated web navigator with "click" and "retrieve" capabilities

Tags: networking, curl, socket, opensource-projects

In our company, several clients provide the detailed information information that we need in a web site. The amount of time that our employees spend navigating the remote website is simply ridiculous, specially since the structure is fixed.

I would like to write an automated web navigator, maybe in Python?

I don't want to re-invent the wheel. Have looked around but have been unable to find something that fits my needs.

This is the closest:

http://codedbot.com/questions/4044782/open-url-periodically-without-web-browser

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: Check out [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: The question is implicit. Part of the problem is to extract it.

Answer (score 0):

This previous post seems to be a long way toward a solution:

[Automating web requests using curl?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/automating-web-requests-using-curl)