# How to get the contents of a webpage but after running javascript?

Tags: curl, http, javascript

I am trying to download the contents of a web page using curl but it seems l am missing some content that l suspect to be generated by JavaScript. If the page runs on the browser l am able to get all the contents l require.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/448514/command-line-browser-with-js-support

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automating web requests using curl?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/automating-web-requests-using-curl)

Comment: @Gilles I don't think it's a duplicate. This one here is more complex as it requires Javascript, which `curl` doesn't offer. On the other hand, I would agree it's a duplicate of the [SU question](http://superuser.com/questions/448514/command-line-browser-with-js-support) that [cas](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7696/cas) has suggested

Comment: @roaima Having Javascript was one of the points of that question as well. Both questions are asking for “curl” for the automation plus the trimmings of web browsers such as JS.

Comment: @Gilles I see nothing in your suggested duplicate that requires Javascript. (Someone did ask if it was required but there was no reply.) Furthermore the accepted answer offered `curl`, which [mwiti](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/141397/mwiti) here is already ruling out as inadequate.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to do it.

(From the link, *PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling, CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG.*)