# How can I get a translated string from Google Translate with curl etc?

Tags: command-line, curl

How can I get a translated string, e.g. English to Spanish, from Google Translate with some command line tools like curl? I looked at the page source but Google Translate doesn't seem to include the translation result in its html source even though the result is rendered on the screen. So

```
 curl "https://translate.google.com/#auto/es/stay%20calm"
```

didn't work--just gave me the html source that doesn't have either original string or translated one. And I heard that their API was not free so I don't want to use it. I hear that there's also Microsoft's translation service, but I'd like to stick to Google's if possible.

Comment: I suspect that they make it difficult to use their service outside of a browser with Javascript (you're supposed to use the API if you want to do that). You may need to use something more sophisticated than curl. If so the answers [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/automating-web-requests-using-curl) should help.

Answer (score 3):

You may create this function in your `~/.bashrc`

```
function gtr {
  sl=en
  tl=$1
  shift
  base_url="https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=$sl&tl=$tl&dt=t&q="
  ua='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/109.0'
  qry=$( echo "$*" | sed -e "s/\ /+/g" )
  full_url=$base_url$qry
  response=$(curl -sA "$ua" "$full_url")
  echo "$response" | sed 's/","/\n/g' | sed -E 's/\[|\]|"//g' | head -1
}
```

###### Usage

```
$: gtr es hi this is a test 
Hola esto es una prueba
```

[Source](https://gist.github.com/ayubmalik/149e2c7f28104f61cc1c862fe9834793)