# browser script (automation)

Tags: shell-script, firefox

I want to make Mozilla to run as soon as my pc is on. when Mozilla is open it must be redirected to my internet service provider site and must click on a specific field in that site to enable my login. I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Is this kind of automation possible?

Comment: Does it have to be Mozilla, or will any browser work?  You may be able to automate it with command-line tools, as described in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/automating-web-requests-using-curl

Comment: any other browser. i need to login automatically and do further proceedings.

Comment: @sysadmincrispy did my method helped you ?

Comment: no it just  open firefox and enters the site i need to login automatically and do some clicks at specified postions in webpage.

Comment: once Mozilla is running, you can use `xdotool` to simluate keyboard and mouse actions.

Answer (score 1):

`Upstart` might do your job. Create a file `$HOME/.config/upstart/firefox-with-yoururl.conf` with following content:

```
start on desktop-start
stop on desktop-end

exec firefox <url>
```

Reference : http://ifdeflinux.blogspot.in/2013/04/upstart-user-sessions-in-ubuntu-raring.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to start a browser - I'd use [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey), it can be used to pressing buttons, clicking links and whatsoever the browser can do.

For Chrome there is a [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) - for the same purpose.