# How to reset router through command line browser?

Tags: command-line, browser, router, administration, remote-management

I need to reset router and I just get access with ssh to raspberry in local network with router. I'm trying with elinks and w3m browser but I can't see any option, maybe because the router's control panel is javascript page...

Can you recommend any option to access the option to restart router from the web control panel of the router itself?

Edit: router is provided by Movistar Internet operator. And Movistar offer a access to router through Alejandra web control management. My problem is resolved.

Thanks

Comment: Nobody knows what router you have, how it makes its configuration interface available, or what a "reset" of it may mean.  Many routers have a reset _button_ (possibly only accessible with the end of a paperclip). Few routers (any?) have the same functionality in its configuration interface.

Comment: If you want some help, then you will have to re-write more clearly, specify what the router is, explain how the raspberry pi fits in to all this. Show what you have tried (don't just elude to it), and show what happened.

Comment: Forgive the lack of information. It is a router of the operator Movistar. I just realized that the operator offers a direct access to the router

Comment: This group is about Unix knowlege, not how to deal with routers.

Comment: It is usually possible to use the router's web interface with command line tools (`curl` or `wget`), but it's different for every router.  You may have to examine the page source and/or capture network traffic to find exactly what request to send.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11296/automating-web-requests-using-curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem before and I fixed it by creating an SSH tunnel using Putty.

Comment: Hey, it is a good idea! I will remember it for future problems of this kind or another